# how to fetch partial data from a json in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

let us have a JSON file of having 1000 records like below

```
[{
    "name": "aaa",
    "age": 20
}, {
    "name": "bbb",
    "age": 21
}, ......]
```

Is there any way to get partial data from json like first 100 objects or any,
 if i clicked load more button, then i can have another 100 objects from json,
 preferably in angular 2 or any popular javascript libraries??
 Need to load Partial data from JSON instead of getting all data and taking some part of data
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use JSON.parse() to place the data into an array of objects, then grab the first x number of items from the array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. If you want to get 100 objects from the server, then the server has to send you 100 objects back, whatever framework you use in the front-end.

Comment: no..
my situation here is to load partial from json instead of slicing the data what we get

Comment: Assuming you get a response that's not parsed yet, you could get a sub-string of the response, for example get the string until the 100th } character and parse it as json. Next time, get a substring from 101st to 200th presence of the same } character. There are examples online around getting a substring based on a specific character as delimiter.

Comment: You'll need to show your server-side logic, if you want to get this from the server.

Comment: If this is for display purposes, and you won't be modifying the data at all, I would just store the parsed array of objects in a client side variable for the page and just manipulate it client side to avoid hitting the server over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice function but you should be sure that you have an array of json objects.

```
let startIndex = 0;
let endIndex = 100;

let toBeShowed = yourArray.slice(startIndex ,endIndex);
```

in the next click of your load more button you will increase "**startIndex** ,**endIndex**" with 100 or whatever you want to increase with.

Comment: The goal is not to start with 1000 objects and slice that and take only the first 100. The goal is to get 100 objects at a time from the server directly.

Comment: you want to get 100 by 100 from server ??

Comment: Well yes. That's progressive loading. Do you think Google loads 17 million objects into your browser every time you search for something, and displays only the first page?

Comment: Ok i agree with you totally so what is your back end language ??

Comment: Javascript, why?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see this cant be done by just angular from FE side. you need to support it from BE side. like to send some range of data to BE and it will return this range of results. similar to pagination on tables.

[firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

```
citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population").limit(2)
```